# How do I specify the SessionGroup option?

Tags: configuration

I’ve tried running Tor 0.3.5.8 with the following in a config file:

> SocksPort 9050 SessionGroup=1

I get `[warn] Invalid SocksPort option ‘“SessionGroup=1”’` and Tor fails to start.

Answer (score 0):

[Tor's manpage](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) writes:

> `SocksPort [address:]port|unix:path|auto [flags] [isolation flags]`

So this means the correct name of the option is Socks*Port* and the correct version of the line above is:

```
SocksPort 9050 SessionGroup=1
```

Comment: My bad, there was a typo in the question. My config is as what you wrote when I got the error.